# awk to print matching line or "unknown" if no match

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below I am trying to match each line in `file1` to a line in `file2`. If a match is not found between the two files the the `$1` value from `file1` followed by `unknown` is printed. In the first `awk` I am getting a synatax error near the `else` statement and in the second a syntax on the `next`. I am not sure why the syntax errors as the `else`  is needed to capture the `unknown` condition and the `next` tells `awk` to process the next line, right or am I mistaken in my thinking? Both files are `space-delimited`, Thank you :).

**file1**

```
A2M
A4GALT
A4GNT
ABC34
```

**file2**

```
A2M AD
ABC34 AD/AR
```

**desired output**

```
A2M AD
A4GALT unknown
A4GNT unknown
ABC34 AD/AR
```

**awk**

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1];next}$1 in A else { print "unknown" }' file1 file2

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}  # define field and output seperators
    FNR==NR{ # process each field in line of `file1`
         for (i=1; i <= n; i++) {   # execute loop
         d[$1] = $1  # match first element and read into key d
  }
}
  next   # process next line
}{print $1, ($1 in d?d[$1]:"unknown")}' file1 file2 # if no match 
print $1 followed by unknown
```

Comment: You have a syntax error because your quotes are unbalanced.  Try moving your awk code to a file--a little known  fact about awk is that you can put your code in a file like any other programming language, you don't need to whack it all in a single line.

Comment: I'd be surprised if that fact is "little known", it's right at the top/front of every awk man page, book and the POSIX spec and is used frequently in answers here and in other forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple ***join*** + ***sort*** one-liner to reach the goal:

```
join -a1 -a2 -e "unknown" -o1.1,2.2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

The output:

```
A2M AD
A4GALT unknown
A4GNT unknown
ABC34 AD/AR
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print $1, ($1 in a ? a[$1] : "unknown")}' file2 file1
```

The syntax error in the first script is:

```
$1 in A else
```

You probably meant:

```
!($1 in A)
```

but I'm curious about how you came up with that - what language have you used where `condition else` would be valid syntax for the negation of `condition`? You've asked dozens of questions and received answers - did none of them use a `!` operator?

The syntax error in the second script is because the `next` is outside of any of the `{...}` pairs and you have one too many `}`s. You could have just counted them to see that.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I was trying to follow `awk '{if ($0 == "your_match") {print "match"} else {print "no match"} }'` something like this... but I think `(condition {action}) ` is more of what I needed to try. I did see the additional brace after counting but it was after I posted. I do post a lot but  learn more from them :).

Comment: My point is that AFAIK there's no language where the negation of `IF condition DO action` would be `IF condition ELSE action` and awk just follows the same rules as all other simple, Algol-based languages so there's no reason to guess wildly at the syntax if you don't know it - if you don't want to read the man page or look at other examples of scripts then at least try things that'd work in any other language you're familiar with, not things that wouldn't work in any language.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this one:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]; next }$1 in a{ print $1,$2; delete a[$1] }END{ for ( i in a ) print i, "unknown" }' file1 file2 | sort
```

Output:

```
A2M AD
A4GALT unknown
A4GNT unknown
ABC34 AD/AR
```

Comment: You mean like: awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]; next }$1 in a{ print $1,$2; delete a[$1] }END{ for ( i in a ) print a[i], "unknown" }' file1 file2 | sort ?

Comment: But this is not giving the expected output thats why I did the a[$1]=$1.